# Can I use Istio VirtualService without a Gateway?

Tags: devops, istio, istio-gateway

As shown in the virtual service [docs](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service/), I should not have to create a gateway to use a virtual service. However, when I try to inject a header or reroute a request, nothing happens.

```
# virtual-service.yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: nginx-vs
  namespace: default
spec:
  hosts:
  - nginx-web
  http:
  - headers:
      response:
        add:
          My-Custom-Header1: "abc-123"
    route:
    - destination:
        host: nginx-web
        port:
          number: 80
```

I see that the virtual service has been picked up and is applied to the pod I expect it to.

```
> istioctl x describe pod nginx-deployment-689cbb8758-5s9ss
Pod: nginx-deployment-689cbb8758-5s9ss
   Pod Ports: 15090 (istio-proxy), 80 (nginx-web)
Suggestion: add 'version' label to pod for Istio telemetry.
--------------------
Service: nginx-web
   Port: http-nginxweb 80/HTTP targets pod port 80
VirtualService: nginx-vs
   1 HTTP route(s)
--------------------
Effectve PeerAuthentication:
   Workload mTLS: PERMISSIVE
Skipping Gateway information (no ingress gateway pods)
```

But when I curl I don't see the added header:

```
> curl -v myapp.com
...
< x-envoy-upstream-service-time: 3
< server: istio-envoy
< x-envoy-decorator-operation: nginx-web.default.svc.cluster.local:80/*
< Via: 1.1 google
```

I have also tried rerouting and a few other tasks from the virtual service but nothing is applying. Do I have to use a gateway for this to work, or is it not actually connecting to the service like I think it is?

This deployment works already with Kubernetes Ingress and Kuberenetes Service handling routing. I want to add in a virtual service to handle retries.

**SOLUTION**:
As other have stated, you do have to use the Istio Gateway for any external requests to get to a virutal service.
If you have issues setting up and Istio Gateway, make sure your `istio:` label is correct. If you're installing with helm the label won't necessarily be the default.

Comment: The host you curl against doesn't match the host in the vs spec.

Comment: I thought the host in the vs spec is supposed to be the service to capture traffic from? I tested with setting the host as myapp.com but it made no difference and istioctl wasn't showing the vs as being applied anymore.

Comment: Not 100 % sure of your setup. Your vs is applied to mesh internal traffic only because you applied it to the mesh gateway (default). In that case the host needs to match the k8s service fqdn, but that works only within the mesh. For mesh external traffic you'll need a gateway through which the traffic can enter the mesh and bind your vs to that gw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I use Istio VirtualService without a Gateway?

Istio gateway object would be required for routing the external traffic to application pod inside the kubernetes cluster.  Once gateway object is created it sets up a proxy to act as a load balancer for ports and protocol for ingress.  Please refer istio [gateway](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/gateway/) document for configuring the same.  Below is sample gateway

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: my-gateway
  namespace: some-config-namespace
spec:
  selector:
    app: my-gateway-controller
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - uk.bookinfo.com
    - eu.bookinfo.com
```

Comment: I already have traffic coming in from Kubernetes ingress and hitting a Kubernetes service which I've validated works. I just want to add a virtual service in-between the service and ingress so I can retry.

Comment: When a gateway object is created necessary listeners with host name  will configured for istio to do traffic routing for external traffic.  Without gateway istio will not be able route external traffic